# VB.NET Saving / loading listbox

Tags: vb.net

Hi how can i save load a listbox ?

with settings

Not the textfile stuff

I tried this

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Text = My.Settings.history
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    My.Settings.history = ListBox1.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

but no luck please help

Comment: Do you want to save the entire list or just the selected item?

Answer (score 5):

Every WinForms control has a `Text` property by virtue of inheriting from `Control`. For some controls, like `ListBox`, this property is basically useless.

You probably want the *items* in the `ListBox`. So give `history` a type of `StringCollection` and save/load it like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' This is in case the history setting isn't initialized. '
    If My.Settings.history IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item In My.Settings.history
            ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ' Same reasoning as above. '
    If My.Settings.history Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.history = new StringCollection
    End If

    My.Settings.history.Clear()
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        My.Settings.history.Add(item)
    Next
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'create and populate an array, the items collection is not serializable
Dim LBitem As New ArrayList()
For Each itm As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
LBitem.Add(itm.Value)
Next
‘create an XmlSerializer and use it to populate a memory stream
Dim xs As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ArrayList))
Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Try
xs.Serialize(ms, LBitem)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

‘rewind the stream
ms.Seek(0, 0)
‘read the stream to string, I use a StreamReader to take advantage of ReadToEnd
Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ms)
Dim str As String = sr.ReadToEnd
‘now we can save the string to a database
Here is the code that re-populates the list from an XML string

‘we’ll start with a string of xml called str. I’ll assume it’s already pulled from the database
       'To convert a string to a stream  we have to convert to a byte array first.
       'aStr is str converted to an array of bytes
        Dim uniEncoding As New UnicodeEncoding()
        Dim aStr As Byte() = uniEncoding.GetBytes(str)

      'wrtie the byte array to a stream and rewind it

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        ms.Write(aStr, 0, aStr.Length)
        ms.Seek(0, 0)

      'de-serialize from xml to an array of strings
        Dim LBitem As New ArrayList()
        Dim xs As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ArrayList))

        Try
            LBitem = xs.Deserialize(ms)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

      'load the array into the listbox's items collection
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each itm As Object In LBitem
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itm.ToString)
        Next
```